# Prove that sequence with lim = infinity has minimum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am supposed to prove this sentence: If 
$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }an = + \infty $, then $ (a_{n})_{1}^{\infty } $. However, I have no idea how to begin. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$? Furthermore, your question does not seem to start with a complete sentence: "then $(a_n)_1^\infty$" what?

Comment: Have you tried writing out what it means for $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$ and see if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

You have to prove the following: If $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a sequence of real numbers with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$ then the set $A:=\{a_n|n\geq0\}$ has a minimal element.

*Proof.*  There is an $n_0$ such that $a_n>a_0$ for all $n>n_0$. It follows that
$$\min A=\min\bigl\{a_k\bigm|0\leq k\leq n_0\bigr\}\ .$$